# Interacting with IOTA from mobile application?

Tags: tangle, iota-network, javascript

Is it possible to interact with IOTA Tangle (for example, send a message) using an application installed in a mobile phone? If so, is it possible to install IOTA library in a mobile phone? And if yes, for example a JavaScript code that we use it in desktop computer to send a message or coin to the IOTA Tangle, would be exactly the same in mobile version (iOS or Android)?

Answer (score 2):

Interacting with the IOTA Tangle is just using a [**REST API**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) of [**any full node**](https://iota.readme.io/reference) and since you can do that on every smartphone: **Yes, you can interact with the IOTA Tangle from your smartphone.**

JavaScript can run on any device that has a (*"modern"*) browser. Therefore: Yes, you can use the [iota.lib.js](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js) on your smartphone and you can use the **same code** that you use on your desktop.

If you want to build a mobile app (with icon on homescreen, push notifications, etc.) with JavaScript you can look into technologies for [hybrid mobile apps or Progressive Webapps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40820592/8570608). Or you can build a native app (no JavaScript) using the REST API.

Comment: Javascript is not the only access language. iota being an agnostic protocol to language it's simple about accessing the nodes and uploading your transactions. The latter depends on nodes' software stack as well and what iota iri's interface running on the specific node you connect to offers you